# Obtaining primary key before writing row

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have a postgres database that I'm using to store user audio files.  I'm allowing users to provide a title for the files and that title is used as the last path component for the url of the file location.  I then store the title and the url in my database.  This is clearly not the best way to go about it since i'll run into issues when it comes to renaming and encountering multiple files with the same name.  I think the better approach would be to keep the file title and url completely unrelated and use the primary key that postgres assigns to each file uploaded as the last path component of the url.  However, the url is created before being inserted into the database, so I don't have the primary key readily available.  What would be the proper way of going about this?

This is how I'm currently inserting files:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO files(user_id, title, url, share)'
            'VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) RETURNING id;',
           (user.id, file.title, file.url, file.share))
file_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

One solution would be, before writing a row, I could query for the next available primary key and use that value as the last path component of my url, then write the row. But that requires two calls to the server.

Comment: Is the url really needed, or can it be reconstructed (functionally dependent on)  from the other fields (this is often the case in CMS-like software)

Comment: @wildplasser I didn't think about reconstructing the url.  That would totally eliminate the need for storing the url!

Comment: If you can generate it, there is no need to store it!

Comment: Why don't you just use structure like user_id/file_id/file_name so you can compute the path from id's and name or, if know the type, even without it. The more numeric identifiers replace the chars, the better - if you assign ids you only need the file name.